# How to select several children of an element in CSS

Tags: css

I have an element with id. I try to choose some of its children via CSS selectors. 
 `#myDiv span, #myDiv i` works but I wonder if there is a shorter way for this.

I've tried nested selectors like

```
#myDiv {
  & span, i {
    color: red
  }
}
```

but didn't work.

```css
#myDiv span, #myDiv i {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <span>My Span</span>
  <p>My P</p>
  <i>My I</i>
</div>
```

Comment: Your nested code is in **SCSS** not CSS, and there is no nesting in CSS

Comment: No there isn't, that's how CSS works. And that's also the reason why SCSS is popular, you have to write wayyyy less. in the future this [will be possible with CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is) (not supported anywhere yet)

Comment: @AbdulrahmanHatem Oh thanks. OK is there another way?

Comment: Just do `#myDiv > *:not(p)` - will select all children except paragraphs. Using [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) and [CSS :not pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

Comment: Native CSS _might_ also get this at some point in the future, there is a proposal for it at least: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-nesting/Overview.bs

Comment: @AbdulrahmanHatem @cloned @skobaljic @CBroe Thanks a lot. It seems using `#myDiv :is(span, i)` is sensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nested code is in **SCSS** not in CSS, and **there is no nesting in CSS**.

The **shortest CSS code** if you will not add any another elements under this container in future will be

```
#myDiv *:not(p) {
   color: red
}
```

Comment: using * is not a good idea..., what if later on there is a a tag added for example

Comment: Sure, but for this only code it will be the shortest one!

Comment: so shortest is good, even if it produces problems in the future?

Comment: Never, but if we open all possibilities in future he will change his code may be he will add another ```i``` or ```span``` under the same container without giving them the red color, so he will have to change even his CSS code, no body knows what future brings!

Comment: If you code everything with the mindset "You don't know what the future brings", And "if the output changes i can change that again" the code will get impossible to maintain. The only correct answer is that his code is good as it is.

Comment: I totally agree with your perspective, but i give the shortest code for this condition, and for that i edited my answer to be only for this code condition .

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be recursive (let's say, in the future, some #myDiv elements will have their own child elements), use:

```
#myDiv > *:not(p) {
   color: red
}
```

Comment: The`*` is never a good idea. That would mean that if there is a new `a` tag in the future it will color red too. And it will also color the p tag red.

Comment: I didn't notice the `p` tag requirement. modified answer.

Comment: Now your answer is the same as the accepted answer. just saying

Comment: No it's not. I'm using the arrow sign which means immediate children of the selected element.

Comment: My bad. its better than the accepted answer. Still i would never use the `*` selector.

Answer (score -3):

You can like this:

```
#myDiv {
  & span, & i {
    color: red
  }
}
```

it seems that you forgot to put "&" before every new class selector.

Comment: Both `&` are not needed. and nesting does not work in CSS